# Exporting Spring Boot JAR for remote deployment

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, package

I need to export a JAR file for remote deployment of my spring boot application. I am successfully able to generate it for my local deployment. But when I change the mySQL database credentials to my remote host's local mySQL client, the jar export is failing with

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am using the `mvn package` command to export jar file. Why is the package command trying to execute the project rather than just packaging it? How can I export a jar for remote deployment?

Comment: I suppose it runs tests where uses db connection properties

Comment: How to resolve the same?

Comment: You can skip it for build, tro to add -Dmaven.test.skip to your command

Comment: Thanks, that worked.. Can you please post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it runs tests where uses db connection properties. You can skip it for build, try to add

`-Dmaven.test.skip` to your command